# Responsive Blog with comments

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog, responsive

I am new to Office 365 and SharePoint Online (2016) only worked with 2013 Foundation before. 
Does anybody have any idea regarding responsive blogs with the ability to comment in the Online version?
A new "blog" site is not responsive.
I like the new "modern" sites, which are ootb responsive. Using a Yammer Webpart underneath I have the ability to comment under the newswebpart. But I cannot comment on a single news/blog entry, only in my news yammer group which is showing the newest posts.

Any ideas/solutions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[image]

it can be done by using Newsfeed, but you need to swich back your pages to Classic mode.

Comment: thank you for this info. Maybe I'm missing something, but I cannot find "site feed" under social collobaration, only "site users", do i need a special site?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to activate Site Feed feature in Site Settings --> Manage site features.

Comment: the site feed is activated. I searched the internet found [link](http://www.sharepointmaestra.com/Blog/Post/41/Where's-the-Site-Feed-Newsfeed-MicroFeed-Web-Part-) but do not have the "web parts"